# progress bar with vuejs

Tags: css, vue.js

I have a progress bar that amount increments when I click it, but I am trying to make the width increment as well. I have tried binding the style class to "score" but that breaks it. I presume I am mission some logic to increase the width. any help would be great

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <div id="app">
      {{score}} <button v-on:click="incrementBy20">Click</button>

      <div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" v-bind:aria-valuenow="score" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:70%">
  {{this.score}}
  </div>
</div>
      </div>
    

<script>
    
    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        score: 0
      },
     
      methods:{
          incrementBy20:function(){
              this.score+=20;
          },
          
      },
      mounted:function(){
         this.incrementBy20()
         
    }
        
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you should be able to bind style to score like this `:style="{ width: score + '%' }"`. How did you bind it? also your data should be a [function](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function)

Comment: No worries. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to directly bind your score to your progress bar maybe you should consider to limit your score to 100 since the max value of the progress bar is, indeed, 100. Your snippet could be like this:

```
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <div id="app">
      {{score}} <button v-on:click="incrementBy20">Click</button>

      <div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" v-bind:aria-valuenow="score" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" :style="{width: score+'%'}">
  {{this.score}}
  </div>
</div>
      </div>


<script>

    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        score: 0
      },

      methods:{
          incrementBy20:function(){
                let newScore = this.score + 20;
              this.score = newScore >= 100 ? 100: newScore; 
          },

      },
      mounted:function(){
         this.incrementBy20()

    }
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Otherwise, you could use a computed var to build your progress bar:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <div id="app">
      {{score}} <button v-on:click="incrementBy20">Click</button>

      <div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" v-bind:aria-valuenow="score" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" :style="{width: progressWidth+'%'}">
  {{this.score}} / {{this.maxScore}}
  </div>
</div>
      </div>


<script>

    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        score: 0,
        maxScore: 3000
      },

      methods:{
          incrementBy20:function(){
                let newScore = this.score + 20;
              this.score = newScore >= this.maxScore ? this.maxScore: newScore; 
          },
      },
      computed: {
        progressWidth(){
            return (this.score * 100) / this.maxScore;
        }
      },
      mounted:function(){
         this.incrementBy20()

    }
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

> [andrew1325](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10526685/andrew1325) allready given you the answer in comment. i just added
>   the solution in solution panel

```
<body>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <div id="app">
      {{score}} <button v-on:click="incrementBy20">Click</button>

      <div class="progress">
         <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" v-bind:aria-valuenow="score" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" 
            :style="{ width: score + '%' }"> {{this.score}}
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>

<script>
    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: function(){
        return{
           score: 0
        }
      },

      methods:{
          incrementBy20:function(){
              this.score+=20;
          },

      },
      mounted:function(){
         this.incrementBy20()

    }

    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```